# How to count the number of true elements in a NumPy bool array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count, boolean

I have a NumPy array 'boolarr' of boolean type. I want to count the number of elements whose values are `True`. Is there a NumPy or Python routine dedicated for this task? Or, do I need to iterate over the elements in my script?

Comment: For pandas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053849/counting-non-zero-values-in-each-column-of-a-dataframe-in-python

Answer (score 353, accepted):

You have multiple options. Two options are the following.

```
boolarr.sum()
numpy.count_nonzero(boolarr)
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> boolarr = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]], dtype=np.bool)
>>> boolarr
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

>>> boolarr.sum()
5
```

Of course, that is a `bool`-specific answer. More generally, you can use `numpy.count_nonzero`.

```
>>> np.count_nonzero(boolarr)
5
```

Comment: Thanks, David. They look neat. About the method with sum(..), is True always equal to 1 in python (or at least in numpy)? If it is not guaranteed, I will add a check, 'if True==1:' beforehand. About count_nonzero(..), unfortunately, it seems not implemented in my numpy module at version 1.5.1, but I may have a chance to use it in the future.

Comment: @norio Regarding `bool`: boolean values are treated as 1 and 0 in arithmetic operations. See "[Boolean Values](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values)" in the Python Standard Library documentation. Note that NumPy's `bool` and Python `bool` are not the same, but they are compatible (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types) for more information).

Comment: @norio Regarding `numpy.count_nonzero` not being in NumPy v1.5.1: you are right. According to this [release announcement](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-May/056295.html), it was added in NumPy v1.6.0.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies with the links!

Comment: FWIW, `numpy.count_nonzero` is about a thousand times faster, in my Python interpreter, at least.

`python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; bools = np.random.uniform(size=1000) >= 0.5" "np.count_nonzero(bools)"`
vs.
`python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; bools = np.random.uniform(size=1000) >= 0.5" "sum(bools)"`

Comment: @chbrown you are right. But you should compare to `np.sum(bools)` instead! However, `np.count_nonzero(bools)` is still ~12x faster.

Comment: If I try either of those, it works as long as my answer is non-zero. But if I get 0 and I'm doing it in a pivot table, my answer is always False.

Comment: If you intend to check if there are more 1 or more elements in the array after true values have been counted, you can do this with `np.any(bools)`

Comment: @DavidAlber `numpy.count_nonzero` returns wrong results for masked array.
If masked array has some mask values and all True values in other cells, it's different from `np.sum()`. Is it bug or expected result?

Answer (score 34):

That question solved a quite similar question for me and I thought I should share :

In raw python you can use `sum()` to count `True` values in a `list` :

```
>>> sum([True,True,True,False,False])
3
```

But this won't work :

```
>>> sum([[False, False, True], [True, False, True]])
TypeError...
```

Comment: You should "flatten" the array of arrays first. unfortunately, there's no builtin method, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Thanks Guillaume! Works with Pandas dataframes as well.

Comment: The raw built-in `sum` is much slower for Pandas `DataFrame`s and numpy arrays than their respective `sum` methods.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of comparing two numpy arrays and counting the number of matches (e.g. correct class prediction in machine learning), I found the below example for two dimensions useful:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.random.randint(3,size=(5,2)) # 5x2 random integer array
target = np.random.randint(3,size=(5,2)) # 5x2 random integer array

res = np.equal(result,target)
print result
print target
print np.sum(res[:,0])
print np.sum(res[:,1])
```

which can be extended to D dimensions.

The results are:

Prediction:

```
[[1 2]
 [2 0]
 [2 0]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

Target:

```
[[0 1]
 [1 0]
 [2 0]
 [0 0]
 [2 1]]
```

Count of correct prediction for D=1: `1`

Count of correct prediction for D=2: `2`

Answer (score 2):

```
b[b].size
```

where `b` is the Boolean ndarray in question. It filters `b` for `True`, and then count the length of the filtered array.

This probably isn't as efficient `np.count_nonzero()` mentioned previously, but is useful if you forget the other syntax. Plus, this shorter syntax saves programmer time.

Demo:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([0,1,3])

In [2]: a
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 3])

In [3]: a[a>=1].size
Out[3]: 2

In [5]: b=a>=1

In [6]: b
Out[6]: array([False,  True,  True])

In [7]: b[b].size
Out[7]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolarr.sum(axis=1 or axis=0)
```

axis = 1 will output number of trues in a row and axis = 0 will count number of trues in columns
so

```
boolarr[[true,true,true],[false,false,true]]
print(boolarr.sum(axis=1))
```

will be
(3,1)

Answer (score 0):

For 1D array, this is what worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
numbers= np.array([3, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 
                  5, 2, 4, 2, 6, 6, 3, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5])

numbersGreaterThan2= np.count_nonzero(numbers> 2)
```