# Counting non zero values in each column of a DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas DataFrame in which first column is `"user_id"` and rest of the columns are tags(`"Tag_0"` to `"Tag_122"`).

I have the data in the following format:

```
UserId  Tag_0   Tag_1
7867688 0   5
7867688 0   3
7867688 3   0
7867688 3.5 3.5
7867688 4   4
7867688 3.5 0
```

My aim is to achieve `Sum(Tag)/Count(NonZero(Tags))` for each user_id

`df.groupby('user_id').sum()`, gives me `sum(tag)`, however I am clueless about counting non zero values.

Is it possible to achieve `Sum(Tag)/Count(NonZero(Tags))` in one command?

Answer (score 176):

My favorite way of getting number of nonzeros in each column is

```
df.astype(bool).sum(axis=0)
```

For the number of non-zeros in each row use

```
df.astype(bool).sum(axis=1)
```

(Thanks to Skulas)

If you have nans in your df you should make these zero first, otherwise they will be counted as 1.

```
df.fillna(0).astype(bool).sum(axis=1)
```

(Thanks to SirC)

Comment: I think you meant to axis=0.
If you do axis=1 you'd be counting non zero **rows**

Comment: @skulas Good catch! I guess most people come here for rows and that is why no-one has complained before :)

Comment: Thats a great one liner! To get all the column values which are not null

Comment: @Amir would datetypes ever be zero though?

Comment: It is dangerous if you have nan in your dataframe, they would contribute to the sum.

Comment: Good catch, SirC! Updating my answer.

Answer (score 37):

Why not use `np.count_nonzero`?

1. To count the number of non-zeros of an entire dataframe, `np.count_nonzero(df)`
2. To count the number of non-zeros of all rows
   `np.count_nonzero(df, axis=0)`
3. To count the number of non-zeros of all columns
   `np.count_nonzero(df, axis=1)`

It works with dates too.

Comment: Thanksfor this answer! I ended up with this solution as I think it is very human-readable. I only modified two things: For my understanding of "getting the number of non-zero values for all rows" (your case 2) I needed `axis=1` instead of `axis=0`. And I preferred to get the output as `pandas.Series`, so I used `result = pd.Series(index=df.index, data=np.count_nonzero(df, axis=1))`

Answer (score 14):

To count nonzero values, just do `(column!=0).sum()`, where `column` is the data you want to do it for.  `column != 0` returns a boolean array, and True is 1 and False is 0, so summing this gives you the number of elements that match the condition.

So to get your desired result, do

```
df.groupby('user_id').apply(lambda column: column.sum()/(column != 0).sum())
```

Comment: @BrenBram What shall be the approach if we have negative values in some of the cells?

Comment: @HarshSingal: `column != 0` will find all values that are not zero, regardless of whether they're positive or negative.

Comment: Sorry for not stating the problem precisely.
When I implemented above method the user_id's for which the SUM(Tags) was negative returned -inf in the output while positive SUM(Tags) performed perfectly.
I have been unable to figure out why!

Comment: @HarshSingal: You could get `inf` if there were no nonzero tags (so that the count of nonzero tags was zero).  Your original formulation is not well-defined for that case, so you'll need to think about what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but it seems OP's aim is different from the question title:

> My aim is to achieve Sum(Tag)/Count(NonZero(Tags)) for each user_id...

---

For OP's aim, we could replace 0 with NaN and use `groupby` + `mean` (this works because `mean` skips NaN by default):

```
out = df.replace(0, np.nan).groupby('UserId', as_index=False).mean()
```

Output:

```
    UserId  Tag_0  Tag_1
0  7867688    3.5  3.875
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension to get the count of non-zero values in each column of df:

```
[np.count_nonzero(df[x]) for x in df.columns]
```