# Fast counts of elements of numpy array by value thresholds in another array

Tags: python, numpy, cumulative-frequency

Given a `numpy` array of threshold values, what is the most efficient way to produce an array of the counts of another array meeting these values?

Assume the threshold value array is small and sorted, and the array of values to be counted is large-ish and unsorted.

**Example:** for each element of `valueLevels`, count the elements of `values` greater than or equal to it:

```
import numpy as np

n = int(1e5) # size of example

# example levels: the sequence 0, 1., 2.5, 5., 7.5, 10, 5, ... 50000, 75000
valueLevels =  np.concatenate(
                   [np.array([0.]), 
                    np.concatenate([ [ x*10**y for x in [1., 2.5, 5., 7.5] ] 
                                   for y in range(5) ] ) 
                    ]
                )

np.random.seed(123)
values = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1e5, size=n)
```

**So far I have tried** the list comprehension approach.

- `np.array([sum(values>=x) for x in valueLevels])`was unacceptably slow
- `np.array([len(values[values>=x]) for x in valueLevels])` was an improvement
- sorting `values` did speed up the comprehension (in the example, from ~7 to 0.5 ms), but the cost of sort (~8 ms) exceeded the savings for one-time use

The best I have right now is a comprehension of [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8364723/2573061):

```
%%timeit 
np.array([np.count_nonzero(values>=x) for x in valueLevels])
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop
```

which is acceptable for my purposes, but out of curiosity,

**What I would like to know** is

- If list comprehension is the way to go, can it be sped up? Or,
- Are other approaches faster? (I have a vague sense that this could be done by broadcasting the values array over the thresholds array, but I can't figure out how to get the dimensions right for `np.broadcast_arrays()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest I have so far is

```
%timeit count_nonzero(values >= atleast_2d(valueLevels).T, axis=1)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 860 µs per loop
```

`sum` is slower:

```
%timeit sum(values >= atleast_2d(valueLevels).T, axis=1)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.5 ms per loop
```

@Divakar's version is even slower:

```
%timeit count_nonzero(values[:, None] >= valueLevels, axis=1)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.86 ms per loop
```

However, I would probably still use your list comprehension, which is not much slower and does not create a big 2D boolean array as an intermediate step:

```
%timeit np.array([np.count_nonzero(values>=x) for x in valueLevels])
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 987 µs per loop
```

Comment: It's good to know how to do the 2D approach, +1.  Performance-wise, I'm not seeing a conclusive difference either.  I'll accept this if nothing superior comes along.  Thanks.

Comment: Yup, I added the new axis along the longer array by mistake, paying the penalty there. Good job with the `count_nonzero`!

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1** Using [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
values.size - np.searchsorted(values,valueLevels,sorter=values.argsort())
```

**Approach #2** Using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(values[:,None]>=valueLevels).sum(0)
```

Comment: Approach #1 needs whole 8.06 ms per loop

Comment: This helps answer the question by establishing that the broadcasting approach is not necessarily faster -- +1

Comment: @TimFuchs And sorting on a huge array didn't help either :)

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 If `values` were already sorted, we would avoid that `sorter` in `np.searchsorted` and the speedup would be huge then.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Also, `broadcasting` is faster, as done in @ Tim's post using `atleast_2d`.