# Count number of trues in a numpy array in each row?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to return the count of `true` values for each row.

for example I have a numpy array:

```
[[False False False ..., False False False]
 [False False False ..., False False False]
 [False False False ..., False  True False]
 ..., 
 [False False False ..., False False False]
 [ True False  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [False False False ..., False False False]]
```

and the return value should be like:

```
[10
 15
 8
 ..., 
 11
 10
 12]
```

[This question asks about how to do it for the whole array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364674/python-numpy-how-to-count-the-number-of-true-elements-in-a-bool-array) but how do I do it for each row?

Comment: Did you check the docs for either of the solutions suggested in that answer? Both [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and [`numpy.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) take an optional `axis` argument.

Comment: I don't know about numpy with with plain python, something like: `r = [len(filter(None, a)) for a in source]` with `source` being your original list

Comment: @user2357112 thanks I found it out.

Comment: Added a [community wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45519545/4909087) to the linked question, since that generates a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can simply do this by providing an `axis` argument to the `sum` function:

```
arr.sum(axis=1)
```